# GraphQL API Querying

Tags: python, api, python-requests

I am new to API's and am struggling to query it. I  managed to get the below to work, but that is all.

```
query = """{
 player(slug:"nico-schlotterbeck") {
   firstName
   lastName
   position
   cardPositions
   id
   slug
   activeClub {
     name
   }
   age
   so5Scores(last:5) {
     score
   }
 }
}"""
```

The below does not seem to be working and I am unsure why?

```
query = """{
  card(slug:"nico-schlotterbeck") {
   assetId
 }
}"""
```

The link for the playground is https://api.sorare.com/graphql/playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While `card()` accepts a slug, it is not a `player.slug` it is a `card.slug` so you need to find out valid data for your player:

```
{
  allCards(playerSlugs: ["nico-schlotterbeck"]) {
    nodes {
      slug
      player{slug}
      name
    }
  }
}
```

Will give you a list of all that players card slugs

Alternatively, you can get them from `player`:

```
{
  player(slug: "nico-schlotterbeck") {
    firstName
    lastName
    slug
    cards{nodes{slug}}
  }
}
```

From either we can file a bunch of card slugs like:

```
"nico-schlotterbeck-2022-common-d60f209d-0e32-47a2-8e8d-1c2406cde20e"
```

and using it was can query `card`

```
{
  card(slug:"nico-schlotterbeck-2022-common-d60f209d-0e32-47a2-8e8d-1c2406cde20e") {
   assetId
 }
}
```

**If what you seek are the `assetId` you can also directly get that from `player`:**

```
{
  player(slug: "nico-schlotterbeck") {
    firstName
    lastName
    slug
    cards{nodes{
      assetId
    }}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. Building off of that, there are different rarities of this player and I need the slugs of all rarities. I have played around with it but have had no luck